# How do I compare a value from a list with a nested object in another list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, comparison

I need to compare a url with the values inside href test1 and test2. I am new to JavaScript and am not sure how to loop to get and compare the values

```
“List1”: [
{
  “type”: “text”,
 “text”: “Test text”
 },
 “type”: “text”,
 “text”: “test1”,
 “marks”: [
     {
       “type”: “link”,
       “attrs”: {
           “href”: “test1”
            }
      }
  ]
  },
   “type”: “text”,
   “text”: “test2”,
    “marks”: [
      {
       “type”: “link”,
       “attrs”: {
           “href”: “test2”
              }
        }
     ]
   }
 ]
```

->

```
for(let I = 0; I < content.length; I++) {
if(my_url === content[I].marks[0].attrs.href {
 Do something….
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code :

```
// Assuming `content` is the JavaScript object you provided

// The URL you want to compare
const my_url = "https://example.com/test1";

// Loop through the "List1" array
for (let i = 0; i < content.List1.length; i++) {
  const item = content.List1[i];

  // Check if the item has "marks" property and it is an array
  if (item.marks && Array.isArray(item.marks)) {
    // Loop through the "marks" array
    for (let j = 0; j < item.marks.length; j++) {
      const mark = item.marks[j];

      // Check if the "attrs" property exists and it has the "href" property
      if (mark.attrs && mark.attrs.href) {
        // Compare the URL with the "href" value
        if (my_url === mark.attrs.href) {
          // URL matches, do something
          console.log("URL match found!");
          console.log("Text:", item.text);
          console.log("Type:", item.type);
          // You can perform additional actions here
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```